# Manipulating a histogram plot in R

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I have a histogram, and I want to move it over by 10 units on the x axis.

```
h1 <- hist(t1,breaks=15)
plot(h1,xlim=c(0,200),col="red")
```

how can I do this?

Comment: You are starting to abuse SO with your question-a-minute rapid fire.

Comment: I would clarify that the problem here is not the question rate, so much as not spending time clarifying and improving previous questions based on the feedback you get before you ask another one that only somewhat different.

Comment: this is a completely different question. can you guys just help?

Comment: Could you start by clarifying your question? Move over a histogram? What do you mean by that? The plot should show the histogram as `hist()` created it. You could shift it by subtracting 10 from t1, but that is a different histogram. Perhaps you can start with `?hist`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your original is:

```
h1 <- hist(t1,breaks=15)
plot(h1,xlim=c(0,200),col="red")
```

then does this do it?

```
h1 <- hist(t1,breaks=15)
plot(h1,xlim=c(-10,190),col="red")
```

Not having your t1 data, I can't tell. But is that what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your brakes
eg:

```
b<-seq(range(t1)[1],range(t1)[2],length.out=15)
```

which you can then manipulate

```
b<-seq(range(t1)[1],range(t1)[2],length.out=15)-10
h1<-hist(t1, breaks=b)
```